# How can I load Deep learning model only once so that the problem of loading the model every time while calling API in Django is reduced?

Tags: django, deep-learning

I am trying to load the heavy pretrained model which size is larger than 1 GB though API using Django. The model is loaded every time I call API which is time consuming. What can be the solution for this ?

I was expecting to load model only once and can use methods while calling API.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simply load your model in apps.py, something like this:

```
# myapp/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
import torch

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    # Load the pretrained model during application initialization
    model = torch.load('path_to_model.pth')
```

Afterwards, in your views, you can access the model like this:

```
from .apps import MyAppConfig
model = MyAppConfig.model
```

[PS] you can also create a Singleton Model Wrapper in order to ensure that only one instance of the model is created and shared across API calls.

Comment: This may still not be a singleton in that in a "production-quality" deployment, you may have multiple processes running your project. Each one of those instances would be local to the process in which it was started. You may have one instance of the model in the database, but their contents may diverge among those memory-resident instances.